# Graphql subscriptions or pollInterval ? Differences in different cases?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm currently watching a course using MERNG stack, and it's basically an app where you post stuff, and something I was trying to achieve by myself was to get posts in real time to all users, so, my first thought was, ok, let's use graphql subscriptions, and in react using apollo/client i made this code to get new posts in real time

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useQuery, useSubscription, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";

import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import PostCard from "../components/PostCard";
import PostForm from "../components/PostForm";

import { FETCH_POSTS_QUERY } from "../util/graphql";

const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { loading, data: { getPosts: posts } = {} } = useQuery(
    FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
    // {
    //   pollInterval: 500
    // }
  );

  const { data: { newPost: post } = {} } = useSubscription(POSTS_REAL_TIME);

  return (
    <Grid columns={3}>
      <Grid.Row className="page-title">
        <Grid.Column>
          <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Row>
        {user && (
          <Grid.Column>
            <PostForm />
          </Grid.Column>
        )}
        {loading ? (
          <h1>Loading Posts...</h1>
        ) : (
          posts &&
          posts.map(post => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column key={post.id} style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
                <PostCard post={post} />
              </Grid.Column>
            );
          })
        )}
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const POSTS_REAL_TIME = gql`
  subscription {
    newPost {
      id
      body
      createdAt
      username
      likes {
        username
      }
      likeCount
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
      }
      commentCount
    }
  }
`;

export default Home;
```

And i was like, ok, but... i couldn't show them in the page because i didn't know how to push that object into my array of posts that comes from my useQuery at the beginning

so i look how to stay the client updated with subscriptions, and i found a post where it shows the documentation of graphql, saying that, you shouldn't update your client using subscriptions, instead, use
pollInterval

```
const { loading, data: { getPosts: posts } = {} } = useQuery(
    FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
    {
      pollInterval: 500
    }
  );
```

So, that literally means that, i spent 2 hours trying a weird code, while, with only one line of code i can do that, so, does pollInterval replace subscriptions? how should i use subscriptions ? if i use pollInterval to keep everyone updated, is that bad for performance or something ?

Thank you for your time comunnity !

Comment: Its push vs pull. When visiting grandma, poll interval is the child asking "are we there yet" every few minutes. Subscription is the child that takes a nap the whole way to be woken up on arrival. They both have pros and cons and fit different use cases. Constant updates benefit from subscription. If you only update every few hours, leaving a websocket open is a waste.

Comment: Cool mate, thank you for your answer, so i guess if i use pollInterval, it woudl be ok to do what i want !

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but I think polling is not the right way to get that done, beacuse you will continuously try to refresh the data and you will be wasting resources from your server. I would use subscriptions([Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#gatsby-focus-wrapper), [Apollo Client(react)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/)), or something like [socket.io](https://socket.io), both use websockets under the hood so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, but, is you're using graphql you can use subscriptions, because it uses web sockets, so there's no reason to use socket.io, but i couldn't figure out how to add that new object of my subscriptions to my current data :/

Comment: Me too. But I need my update instantly and they strictly said polling should be used "
"intermittently" (meaning at irregular intervals; not continuously or steadily). From what I'm getting I can't use this every second. So what's the point? I need instant update. That's why I want to use subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the issue is not that your subscription wasn't working, but you wanted to keep the old data in the view and the new post coming in. What you need to do is keep the old data in React state or using apollo state/cache. So, rather than update the view with the new post, you update the state with the latest post, forcing a rerender of your component.

Comment: Yes, i mean, what pollInterval is basically doing, is calling the useQuery eve 500miliseconds to know if there's knew update stuff